# Comparison of classes in R

Tags: r

I'm updating a R-package, but I confess that I haven't using the R language for four years, so I've forgotten a lot of things. I uploaded my package to CRAN, and they provided me some warnings and notes.I managed to solve the warnings, but I still have an issue with a line of my code.

The line is written as follows:

```
if (class(file) == "data.frame" || class(file2) == "data.frame")
```

CRAN returned the following issue:

```
Found if() conditions comparing class() to string:
File 'DFA/R/DFA.R': if (class(file) == "data.frame" || class(file2) == "data.frame") ...
File 'DFA/R/DFA.R': if (class(file) == "data.frame" || class(file2) == "data.frame") ...
File 'DFA/R/DFA.R': if (class(file) == "data.frame" || class(file2) == "data.frame") ...
File 'DFA/R/DFA.R': if (class(file) == "data.frame" || class(file2) == "data.frame" || class(file3) == "data.frame" || class(file4) == "data.frame") ...
Use inherits() (or maybe is()) instead.
```

Does Anyone know how to adapt my code to use inherits() or is() without losing the original meaning?

Comment: `is.data.frame(file)` or `is(file, 'data.frame')` or `inherits(file, 'data.frame')`

Comment: Just use `if(inherits(file, "data.frame") || inherits(file2, "data.frame"))`. More complex objects (like a `tibble`) will have a `class()` vector with multiple class names (`c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")`), where each "inherits from the right": a `tbl_df` is a subclass of `tbl`, and `tbl` is a subclass of `data.frame`. So `class(file) == "data.frame"` might end up comparing two character vectors of disparate lengths.  By contrast, `inherits(file, "data.frame")` will search "rightwards" in the `class()` names, find `"data.frame"` as a superclass, and return a **single `TRUE`** for `if (...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your line to this:

```
if (inherits(file, "data.frame") || inherits(file2, "data.frame"))
```

`inherits()` is a safer way to check for class as objects can have multiple classes.

Answer (score 4):

You should almost certainly use

```
 inherits(file, "data.frame")
```

instead of `class(file) == "data.frame"`.

That says that `"data.frame"` is one of the classes for those variables.  For example tibbles have class `c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")`, so tibbles would give a positive result.

If you want to exclude tibbles and anything else except objects whose class is `"data.frame"` and nothing else, then you could use

```
identical(class(file), "data.frame")
```